# required missing class in execution of jaxws-maven-plugin wsgen

Tags: web-services, maven, jax-ws, maven-plugin, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm building a java web service using `jax-ws`. i'm using the code-first approach with `jaxws-maven-plugin` to generate the wsdl. the problem is that i'm getting the following error from maven and i can't figure why a `jax-rs` class is required. i'm using the wildfly 8.1.0 bom for javaee7 api resolution (i don't know if it's conflicting with the jaxws-maven-plugin).

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsgen    
(generate-wsdl) on project e-chapaa-services: Execution generate-wsdl of goal 
org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsgen failed: A required class was
missing while executing org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsgen: 
    javax/ws/rs/core/Application
```

the plugin configuration is as follows

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <executions>
        <execution>
             <id>generate-wsdl</id>
             <phase>process-classes</phase>
             <goals>
                  <goal>wsgen</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                  <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the configuration section of the plugin, i had to add the endpointclass implementation with `<sei></sei>` and it worked.